# Setting the color bounds for a matplotlib streamplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I create a grid of streamplots (using subplot) they all have their own color bounds. There doesn't appear to be an option for manually setting the color bounds and hence I can't figure out how to make multiple streamplots share the same color bounds.

For example, [my plot of the wind in the upper atmosphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKcVf.jpg) uses the following code to create the streamplots:

```
magnitude = (u ** 2 + v ** 2) ** 0.5
ax.streamplot(x, y, u, v, color=magnitude)
```

The wind speed/magnitude during winter (JJA) is much stronger than during summer (DJF), however you don't get that impression from the plot because each subplot has its own individual color bounds.

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [set_clim](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.set_clim), which is similar to the `caxis` function in MATLAB. This normalizes the colormap to the specified range.

`ax.set_clim(vmin=minvalue, vmax=maxvalue)`

Comment: This would work for a regular contour plot but not a streamplot. If I run the following: `cf = ax.contourf()` then ask for `dir(cf)` it has all sorts of methods and members including `cf.set_clim`, however if I run `cf = ax.streamplot()` then the only methods or members it has is `cf.arrows` and `cf.lines`. There's no `set_clim`, `vmax` or `vmin`.

Comment: @DamienIrving you can pass a [norm parameter](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) when you call streamplot, that should fix the normalisation.

Comment: @andreabedini Thanks! The `norm` parameter was exactly what I needed.

Comment: How do you use it, @DamienIrving?